# Is CGPathContainsPoint() hardware accelerated?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm doing an iOS game and would like to use this method for collision detection.

As there are plenty (50+) of points to check every frame, I wondered if this method runs on the iDevice's graphics hardware.

Comment: I would measure and see how it performs (on real devices). If its to slow them maybe you can filter down those points by testing against the bounding box of the path first.

Comment: Thanks! Yes im definitely checking the bounding box first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on @DavidRönnqvist point: it doesn't matter if it's "hardware accelerated" or not. What matters is whether it is fast enough for your purpose, and then you can use Instruments to check where it is eating time and try to improve things.

Moving code to the GPU doesn't automatically make it faster; it can in fact make it much slower since you have to haul all the data over to GPU memory, which is expensive. Ideally to run on the GPU, you want to move all the data once, then do lots of expensive vector operations, and then move the data back (or just put it on the screen). If you can't make the problem look like that, then the GPU isn't the right tool.

It is possible that it is NEON accelerated, but again that's kind of irrelevant; the compiler NEON-accelerates lots of things (and running on the NEON doesn't always mean it runs faster, either). That said, I'd bet this kind of problem would run best on the NEON if you can test lots of points (hundreds or thousands) against the same curves.

You should assume that `CGPathContainsPoint()` is written to be pretty fast for the general case of "I have one random curve and one random point." If your problem looks like that, it seems unlikely that you will beat the Apple engineers on their own hardware (and 50 points isn't much more than 1). I'd assume, for instance, that they're already checking the bounding box for you and that your re-check is wasting time (but I'd profile it to be sure).

But if you can change the problem to something else, like "I have a known curve and tens of thousands of points," then you can probably hand-code a better solution and should look at Accelerate or even hand-written NEON to attack it.

Profile first, then optimize. Don't assume that "vector processor" is exactly equivalent to "fast" even when your problem is "mathy." The graphics processor even more-so.

Comment: Thank you mate for your excellent answer. It helped me to really understand the issue and i learned something!